# Cherrypy 3.2 virtual host - application configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy, virtualhost

I am trying to use cherrypy virtualhost dispatcher for serving multiple different applications. 
My idea was to have separate configuration file for each application, but I am kinda lost.
If I use virtualhost dispatcher, all applications are in same namespace, so for example section for database connection can occur only once. Or not? Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my current purposes, I am satisfied with this solution:

I create separate config file for a cherrypy application and I am using the same class as cherrypy for parsing the file.

from cherrypy.lib.reprconf import Config
settings = Config(os.path.join(confPath, "settings.cfg"))

Also, there is python standard module for handling config files named [configparser](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/configparser.html).

This question is also quite irrelevant for me, because serving multiple cherrypy applications (as I thought about it) is quite difficult with cherrypy server. I decided to use cherrypy as WSGI server behind appache and this solves the problem explicitly.