# How can CherryPy alone be used to serve multiple domains?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'd like to use a standalone instance of CherryPy to serve several domains from a single server. I'd like each domain to be served from a completely separate CherryPy application, each with its own configuration file.

I played with [`cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpdispatch.html), but it seems like separate configuration files aren't possible.

A similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650943/cherrypy-3-2-virtual-host-application-configuration)) suggests that this is quite difficult, but doesn't explain why and might have been due to the fact that no one answered the question.

This [CherryPy recipe for multiple apps](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/50aff88dc4e24206518ec32e1c32af043f2729da/deployment/multi_apps/__init__.py?at=default) shows how to load multiple sandboxed apps with separate configuration files, but it looks like they are being served form the same domain.

I can understand that the answer might be, "use CherryPy as a WSGI server behind Nginx or Apache," but I'd rather only deal with CherryPy on this particular server.

Comment: That actually sounds like it's outside the scope of CherryPy as a server (and *should* be - something like Apache or Nginx is better suited to this anyway).

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be out of scope as well, but then I found the hints listed in my original post that suggested it might not be. Given there hasn't been any activity on this thread, I think I'll go with Nginx in front of CherryPy.

Answer (score 1):

In the same repo, there's [vhost recipe](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/50aff88dc4e24206518ec32e1c32af043f2729da/deployment/vhost/__init__.py?at=default). However it uses a shared app. I don't see the way to get `cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost` working with separately mounted apps. This is because `cherrypy.serving.request.app` is set before invocation of the dispatcher. Say you have the following.

```
hostmap = {
  'api.domain.com' : '/app1',
  'www.domain.com' : '/app2'
}
cherrypy.tree.mount(App1(), '/app1', appConfig1)
cherrypy.tree.mount(App2(), '/app2', appConfig2)
```

All what `cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost` does is prepending domain prefix to current url, e.g. requesting `http://www.domain.com/foo` will result in `/app2/foo/` as internal path that is sent to a next dispatcher which is usually `cherrypy.dispatch.Dispatcher`. However the latter will try to find a page handler using current `cherrypy.serving.request.app` which is set to empty app because there's nothing in CherryPy tree that corresonded to `/foo` path. So it will find nothing.

All you need here is to replace prefixing to changing the current app. That is to say changing [that line](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/4939ea9fbe6b0def376fbb349c039c38b0a8994b/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py?at=default#cl-674) to this.

```
cherrypy.serving.request.app = cherrypy.tree.apps[prefix]
```

But because `cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost` is pretty small, you can rewrite in your code easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy
from cherrypy._cpdispatch import Dispatcher


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 80,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }, 
  'hostmap' : {
    'api.domain.com' : '/app1',
    'www.domain.com' : '/app2'
  }
}

appConfig1 = {
  '/' : {
    'tools.json_out.on' : True
  }
}

appConfig2 = {
  '/' : {
    'tools.encode.encoding' : 'utf-8'
  }
}     

def VirtualHost(nextDispatcher = Dispatcher(), useXForwardedHost = True, **domains):

  def dispatch(pathInfo):
    request = cherrypy.serving.request
    domain  = request.headers.get('Host', '')
    if useXForwardedHost:
      domain = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Host', domain)

    prefix = domains.get(domain, '')
    if prefix:
      request.app = cherrypy.tree.apps[prefix]

    result = nextDispatcher(pathInfo)

    # Touch up staticdir config. See
    # https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/614.
    section = request.config.get('tools.staticdir.section')
    if section:
      section = section[len(prefix):]
      request.config['tools.staticdir.section'] = section

    return result

  return dispatch


class App1:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return {'bar': 42}


class App2:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '<em>foo</em>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  config['/'] = {'request.dispatch': VirtualHost(**config['hostmap'])}

  cherrypy.tree.mount(App1(), '/app1', appConfig1)
  cherrypy.tree.mount(App2(), '/app2', appConfig2)

  cherrypy.quickstart(config = config)
```